# Update User-Added Resources to SSL-Friendly URLs?

Tags: wysiwyg, security, video, ssl

I have a field in my publish form where users can add embed code for a video, and they can also embed videos using Wygwam.

The entire site has SSL enabled, but the video embed codes use the insecure "http://" protocol, which breaks the site's SSL.

I don't want my client to have to remember to check the "use https" option on YouTube (and some of the videos are from obscure hosting services anyway).

Is there an add-on or technique I can use to automatically convert those embedded video URL protocols to "https"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your templates you can wrap any custom fields that might contain a non-https embed code with [**Low Replace**](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace), finding and replacing any non-https embed sources.

For example:

```
{exp:low_replace 
    find="http://www.youtube.com/embed" 
    replace="https://www.youtube.com/embed"
}
    {your_custom_field}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

Low Replace will allow you to specify multiple replacements (so you could catch all your different video embed providers in one shot) and has some other useful features, too.

Comment: This is a good idea. I had considered using Low Replace before, but I didn't think to use it for full URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using jQuery for this? This [**answer on StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053882/135935) has a code example that might do the trick.

Here's my quick untested code attempt for your specific case:

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    if (src.indexOf('http:') > -1) {
        src = src.replace('http:', 'https:');
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anna! I think there's potential here, but applying the code directly to an iframe seems to cause problems, as I got this console error: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.mysite.com/blog/my-post from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/Y1iqJqNHX_g. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Comment: Here's another code example to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041352/extract-and-replace-youtube-only-iframe-src

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just have the client enter the video ID and you hard code the iframe embed code into your template. I do this when I need finite control over the video code.

In the field's description, I link to a screenshot showing them how/where to get the video ID from the video URL. Something like this:

[image]

Obviously, this will only work if the video isn't embedded in copy and is a unique field.